# how to multiple times convert value in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a 2 converter.

1. Boolean to Visibility(Bool2Visible) - This converter convert Boolean value to Visibility enum
2. Invert Boolean(InvertBool) - this converter invert Boolean value

My xaml is here

```
<stackpanel Name="A"
          visibility="{Binding isTrue,Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}"/>
<stackpanel Name="B"
          visibility="{Binding isTrue,Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}"/>
```

My goal is If isTrue=true, Stackpanel B will hidden. I need to use InsertBool and use Bool2Visible in Stackpanel B binding.

How to use 2 converter in one time.

Otherwise. `newvalue=Bool2Visible(InsertBool(value))`

If it is impossible, I can to create `InvertAndConvertToVisibility` converter.

Answer (score 3):

> If it is impossible, i can to create InvertAndConvertToVisibility converter.

Personally i would just say to take this option, it is less than 5 minutes worth of work, and if you use a separate converter and name it appropriately it is obvious what you intend to happen.

An alternative is to modify your `Bool2Visible` converter use the `parameter` parameter to pass a flag which indicates that the operation should be negated.

Comment: I would use the parameter, will take even less than 5 minutes of work :) Just add ConverterParameter=False/True for the stackpanels and use bool invert = Convert.ToBoolean(parameter.ToString()) in the converter and you're good to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a special MultiValueConverter if you need to have a value determined from two seperate inputs!

Comment: I know multivalueconverter. but i don't know how to use multivalueconverter in my reason

Comment: When using multiconverters you will have to write another class anyway. So this doesnt solve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can expand Bool2Visible converter with some logic that checks ConverterParameter. In the binding in 2nd StackPanel add ConverterParameter="invertValue" and inside converter class check the value of the parameter(ConverterParameter is automatically passed).

In that way you can handle your problem.